# Can I have two accounts merged into one?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have a main account on Stackoverflow (562440) and an accidental one on Superuser (163236).

would it be possible to merge the SU-account into the SO-account, so my SO-profile is shown on SU and I can keep the lousy 135 points I have gathered on SU so far?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

When I log out in SU and SO and Google. Then log into Google as 'raffaeluni' and then log in to SU and SO using Google. Then SO identifies me as (562440) and SU identifies me as (163236) ... so what can I do? They must be technically linked because of that.
PLUS ... I cannot register a new SU-account linked to my main SO-account, right?

**another observation**

the SU-account is together with the SO-account and several others part of my SE-super-account. But the SU-account is the only one that shows a different username and doesn't inherit the profile information I have entered for my SE-super-account.

**and another observation**

apparently I have to Meta-accounts - one connected with (562440) and another connected with (163236).

1. log out from Meta
2. being logged into Google as "raffaeluni" I log into Meta and am identified as (163236)
3. I go from Meta on my SE-accounts-summary page and choose Meta
4. now I am in Meta as my main account (562440)

does that make sense?

Comment: the 2 accounts are separate & not related.

Comment: well, they are both my accounts ... makes them related.

Comment: All your 13 accounts are already linked to each other, but you can't merge the content from one side into another.

Comment: I don't get that! When I log out in SU and SO and Google. Then log into Google as 'raffaeluni' and then log in to SU and SO using Google. Then SO identifies me as 562440 and SU identifies me as (163236) ... so what can I do? They must be technically linked because of that.

Comment: [su] meta account derives data from [main] site & the sync takes upto an hour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your accounts on a Stack Exchange site are linked, but they are separate & individual on a site-to-site basis and hence it's not possible to merge your Super User account into the Stack Overflow account.

---

> When I log out in SU and SO and Google. Then log into Google as 'raffaeluni' and then log in to SU and SO using Google. Then SO identifies me as (562440) and SU identifies me as (163236) ... so what can I do? They must be technically linked because of that.

Stack Exchange knows that you have an account on Stack Overflow with id 562440 & on Super User with id as 163236 - the 2 accounts are separate in the sense that your content from Stack Overflow & Super User are separate. Yet they are related because you authenticate to both sites with your email id and hence they are linked to you.

---

> But the SU-account is the only one that shows a different username and doesn't inherit the profile information I have entered for my SE-super-account.

The profile sync at times doesn't work, you can force a profile sync by heading over to your [Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/562440/) and select

> Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts

Comment: hmmmmm .... but how can I add an SU account to my main SO-account. Because of the above described behavior I am kept from doing so.

Comment: @user163236 I don't follow you? [se] knows that you have an account on [so] with id 562440 & on [su] with id as 163236 - the 2 accounts are separate in the sense that your content from [so] & [su] are separate. yet they are related because you authenticate to both sites with your email id and hence they are linked to you.

Comment: I clarified in the OP

Comment: I've revised my answer. @user163236

Comment: cool, save and copy did the trick! thanks